# Rails 4 - can ruby tags be used inside select tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, helper

I'm trying to write a select tag that makes use of a helper I've written.

When I write the tag like this, it all works.

```
<%= select_tag "roles", options_from_collection_for_select(@roles, "id", "name"), :multiple => true, :class => 'chosen-select form-control' %>
```

I want to use a helper to present the name of the role differently to the name in the database. I made a helper to do that. Now I'm trying to use that helper method instead of the :name attribute.

```
<%= select_tag "roles", options_from_collection_for_select(@roles, "id", "<%= text_for_role(name)%>"), :multiple => true, :class => 'chosen-select form-control' %>
```

The above attempt doesn't work. I can't find an example of how to use a helper inside a select tag. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to interpret ruby within a string you need to use #{} such as

```
<%= select_tag "roles", options_from_collection_for_select(@roles, "id", "<%= #{text_for_role(name)}%>"), :multiple => true, :class => 'chosen-select form-control' %>
```

You could also directly put your ruby code instead of interpolating:

```
<%= select_tag "roles", options_from_collection_for_select(@roles, "id", text_for_role("name")), :multiple => true, :class => 'chosen-select form-control' %>
```

The above will just solve the error you encountered but i think it doesn't address the issue in the end. If you would like to display a different name than the one in the database, i guess you would need to define text_for_role in the Role model.
and then you call:

```
<%= select_tag "roles", options_from_collection_for_select(@roles, :id, :text_for_role), :multiple => true, :class => 'chosen-select form-control' %>
```

This will call the method text for role for each AR object to set the name attribute in html tag.

Comment: thanks- I tried both of these options. but neither of them works.

Comment: Error for the 1st: syntax error, unexpected $undefined
... :multiple => true, :class => \'chosen-select form-control\'...
...

Comment: Error for 2nd: undefined local variable or method `name' for #<#<Class:0x007ff69cf8f710>:0x007ff6a9cbc3f0>

Comment: I have updated my answer you would have to quote the name:
<%= select_tag "roles", options_from_collection_for_select(@roles, "id", text_for_role("name")), :multiple => true, :class => 'chosen-select form-control' %>

Comment: I tried the updated form. The error message says: nil is not a symbol nor a string
Thanks for your help in trying to solve this. I don't know where nil is coming from in this error

Comment: I guess this function text_for_role("name") is returning nil and provoking the error. You would need to put a debug point inside this function and understand what is happening.

Comment: Could it be because I have that helper method in my roles helper, where this select tag is in my user index?

Comment: I dont think so, helper method are accessible from any views usually. Can you post the code for text_for_role function ?

Comment: the module RolesHelper

 def text_for_role(name)
   case name
    when 'guest'
      'Guest - Trial Account'
    when 'admin'
     'Admin'
    when 'representative'
      'Representative'
    when 'cf_manager'
and so on - it works in other views.

Comment: It is not working because you need to replace name by an actual value from you case statement.

<%= select_tag "roles", options_from_collection_for_select(@roles, "id", text_for_role("guest")), :multiple => true, :class => 'chosen-select form-control' %>

Comment: But I want it to be the collection for select to have all the roles available by the names set out in the helper

Comment: I have updated my answer again, i think this should solve your problem. But then your method doesn't need any parameter, just apply the case statement on self.name

Comment: I tried the new suggestion, but I get this error: undefined method `text_for_role' for #<Role:0x007fe4b92a1840>

Comment: Have you defined this method in the Role model ?

Comment: No- its defined in my roles helper as: def text_for_role(name)

Comment: you would need to move the method in the Role model for my solution to work :)